# After update - Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services, build.gradle

Gradle project sync failed.

After update the android SDK I got this error:

> Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8

- I have checked that the sdk location which is updated is used by Android Studio
- I've got Google Repository installed and Android Support Repository too all up to date.
- Also I have a ANDROID_HOME local variable pointing to the sdk I'm actually using

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try using com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08 instead of 5.2.8.

you can also look for the right version number in your services directory:

.. /android-studio/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/

Comment: Thats it! Thanks mate. But why was suggested version 5.2.8 instead the correct one 5.2.08?

Comment: Thanks, seems that it suggests the version name missing a leading 0.

Answer (score 31):

Check your sdk extras packages, you need to install:

- Google Play services
- Google Repository

For me, the thing was that I didn't have the second one installed and then "---:5+" worked
as described here:

> https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

You can now use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

Even though it warns against it. If things go flakey after an update I'll revert back to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved using:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting using Open File> Project Structure, click the "add (+)", 
searching for "play-service" to select the currently available version.
Something like this image:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pv7j.jpg